# How to manually push stack entry into vim tagstack?

Tags: vim, tags

Just like the title says: "How to manually push stack entry into vim tagstack?"

Here is the problem: I have been using gtags/global + unite.vim plugins for a while (btw, these two plugins are awesome!), but it failed to automatically insert a tag entry into the tagstack. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The tag stack is updated when a) the `tagstack` option is on and b) you use `:tag`-derived commands like `:tselect` or `<C-]>`. The tag stack is AFAIK not accessible via vimscript so you will need to check with your plugins if they actually use one of the tag commands or not.

Answer (score 3):

I use a technique taken from vim-jedi in [vim-tagimposter](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-tagimposter) to push tags into the tagstack. (I believe this is the same technique as lh-tags.)

For 
[omnisharp-vim](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim), you could add this map to **
`ftplugin/cs.vim`**:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>jT :<C-u> TagImposterAnticipateJump <Bar> OmniSharpGotoDefinition<CR>
```

Now you can use `<Leader>jT` to jump to tags, `<C-t>` to jump back, and
`:pop`/`:tag` to navigate up and down the stack. `:tags` will show your tags
prefixed with `IMPOSTER_`.

I think this should work for [gtags.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/gtags.vim):

```
nnoremap <Leader>jT :<C-u> TagImposterAnticipateJump <Bar> GtagsCursor<CR>
```

---

A fancier solution is [the proposed 'tagfunc'](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/1628) which would have you implement a function that returns a list of tags (derived from gtags/global/whatever) and vim would take care of populating the tagstack.

Answer (score 2):

In my very confidential [lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags/) plugin, I had `lh#tags#jump()` function that I use to inject tags and jump to them. The function has now been moved to my vim-library: [`lh#tags#stack#jump()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/tags/stack.vim#L56)

The idea is to always have a fake tagfile (in a tmpdir) where I add jump locations as forged tags, when need be. From there, it's as simple as to jump to `forged_tag_number_000042`. Vim will then automatically take care of maintaining the stack for us.

Answer (score 2):

As of a pretty recent version of vim (use `if has('patch-8.2.0077')` to check if yours is new enough), it's pretty easy to push locations into the tagstack:

```
" Store where we're jumping from.
let pos = [bufnr()] + getcurpos()[1:]
let item = {'bufnr': pos[0], 'from': pos, 'tagname': expand('<cword>')}
YourCommandToJumpToCWord

" Assuming jump was successful, write to tag stack.
let winid = win_getid()
let stack = gettagstack(winid)
let stack['items'] = [item]
call settagstack(winid, stack, 't')
```